# Setup a Dotnet core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord.net

I want to code a application and deploy it on my Raspberry Pi 3.

It will be a discord bot app using [Discord.net library (C#)](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net). To do this i guess i need to use .net core because it will be deployed on another platform than Windows. But i'm not a expert in .net core as a matter of fact i always failed when i tryed to use it ...

Now i really want to succeed with .net core that's why i'm here to find a solution.

What i tryed :

1. I cloned the Discord.net repo from git.
2. I created a new **Console Core Project** using Visual Studio 2017
3. I added project reference to the Discord.net projects to try to use his classes

but i had an error for each Discord.net referenced project :

```
"Unable to resolve "path_to_Discord_net_Project" for ".NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1"
```

I make some search on internet about this error, but without success ...

So my questions are

1. Should i create my new project using dotnet commands in place to use Visual Studio 2017 ?
2. Should i stop using .net core ?
3. Should i stop using Discord.net Libraries ?
4. Can we use .Net Framework library with in combination with .Net Core Console ?
5. Can i code this without using .Net Core (knowing that it will be deployed on my pi )?

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: Why did you clone the repo? There's a NuGet package available which should be way easier to setup

Comment: if seems to exist on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/discord.net - just use  package reference instead of a project reference - much easier

Comment: @MarcGravell small addendum, I think OP needs the 1.0-RC version (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Discord.Net/1.0.0-rc) which targets .NET core - AFAIK the "stable" release only runs on .NET 4.5

Comment: @UnholySheep the default 0.9.6 seems to target .NETStandard 1.3 - that should be sufficient

Comment: why you note usining universal application for Raspberry Pi 3. if you are new on this see this link https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworld

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Effectively, it's easier to use nuget for that. I didn't start by using nuget because often on nuget the last version is not avalaible (difference between nuget package version and github version). But for Discord.Net it's not the case. 

I will use nuget but i wonder how can i do without this ? (in case where one day i would need to add a reference to a project which is not available on nuget).
Thank you the help btw !

Answer (score 1):

watch this [`link`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworld) Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is a common app platform across all version of Windows 10, including Windows 10 IoT Core. UWP is an evolution of Windows Runtime (WinRT)
UWP apps just work on IoT Core, just as they do on other Windows 10 editions. A simple, blank Xaml app in Visual Studio will properly deploy to your IoT Core device just as it would on a phone or Windows 10 PC. All of the standard UWP languages and project templates are fully supported on IoT Core.

and at this [`link`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples)  is many samples for windows iot cores and this applications

Comment: Thank you for answering but i don't want to use windows iot i prefer to use Ubuntu/Raspbian. Matter of habit.